# migration from plone 3.3.5 to 4.1

Tags: plone

After migrating from 3.3.5 to 4.1, some folders show their contents properly while some give this error
AttributeError: getLocallyAllowedTypes
How can I fix it?

faber

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: Here it is [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1JNUrr9Ey5CEwwqpktw_m4QYpqcIbwfIydEbEmjeTR8s/edit?hl=it)

Comment: If I migrate from 3.3.5 to 4.0.8 the folders are all ok, so I think my problem is related to Plone 4.1 (but I still have problems with contentleadimage)

Comment: Please include the full traceback in the question.

Comment: At last contentleadimage is ok (running the upgrade for blob support).

Answer (score 3):

You really need to include more detail when asking others for help.  When asking for help with software, it's very important to include not only tracebacks but also what add-ons you are using.  Your original question should have mentioned that you're using contentleadimage.  It also should have mentioned that you're using Collage, something I only found out from the traceback.

At any rate the problem appears to be that Collage, contentleadimage, or some combination of your add-one are not compatible with 4.1.

Comment: Then that bug doesn't apply, so you're back to my original answer.

Comment: I could migrate to Plone 4.1 installing contentleadimage 1.3.3-dev and Products.ATContentTypes from cvs (Plone 4.1 ticket 11950)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem myself when using wsapi4plone.core to sling content across. Some of my ZODBs have been upgraded all the way from 2.0.5 and we decided this migration would be a good opportunity to 'clean' the content.

The fix is to go to the offending folders on the content source, and from the 'Add new' > 'Restrictions' and check the appropriate choice.

MY suspicion is that these were older folders (prior to the property existing) that had not updated properly and had never been edited since. I didn't dig too deep since there were only a few.

Comment: I decided to create a new Plone 4.0.8 site and to copy/paste the folders from the migrated site: the new site with pasted contents seems ok, while on the "migrated" still have problems.

Comment: You're right: Plone 4.1 has this problem (ticket 11950). As a workaround you can install Products.ATContentTyoes from cvs.